# How to simulate a bimodal distribution in javascript?

Tags: javascript, random, statistics, distribution, simulate

I need to simulate a bimodal distribution in Javascript. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pick any two distinct unimodal distributions, A and B.  Then generate a value by randomizing which one you are generating from.